# Entry title - wordpress css editor

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using wordpress for my website, pilcrow theme
I accidentally removed the title from within the posts 
so... what's the block I should add to bring back the title to the single post and where to add it exactly? 
(P.S: I'm a beginner, so please use human language)

[here's an example of the problem](http://blokeh.com/?p=2904)

Answer (score 0):

Why not [download](https://downloads.wordpress.org/theme/pilcrow.1.5.1.zip) the theme and compare the template source to your edited version?

Search for

```
<?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
```